# How can i set ng-model formdata for ng-repace in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to set ng-model dynamic in Angularjs and in using.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="option in optionListByCategoryId">
 <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-if="option.type == 'number'">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="active">{{option.name}}&nbsp;value = {{formData.optionList[{{option.id}}]}}</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input  type="text" id="{{option.id}}" name="{{option.id}}" ng-model="formData.optionList[{{option.id}}]"  />
  </div>
</div>
```

In html I set ng-model formData and get by id optionList with ng-model optionListByCategoryId.

**Javascript**

```
$scope.formData = {"optionList":{"1eb79b0b8b125270e1fd7ad50c0017e8":3,"1eb79b0b8b125270e1fd7ad50c000eb1":""}}

$scpe.optionListByCategoryId =[{"name":"DISKPLAY","description":"Inch", "active":true, "type":"number","step":1,"max":14,"min":3,"id":"1eb79b0b8b125270e1fd7ad50c0017e8"]
```

Is error in AngularJS.

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 22 of the expression
```

Help me please.

Comment: There are some typos, firstly.  Secondly, you are doing something weird with the id key being inserted as an array position.  That won't work.

What is it exactly you are trying to do???
Here is a plunker.  I corrected a type in 'scope' and added a closing curly brace.  Other than that it's original.
http://plnkr.co/edit/GQMv5gbeQQpYJ0PQM7VE?p=preview

Comment: Definitely when you write wrong code, you will get errors irrespective of the language. what you have written is full of errors. Make amendments and then, you'll get the necessary assistance.

Comment: This `formData.optionList[{{option.id}}]` should just be this `formData.optionList[option.id]`.

Comment: Thank you very much PavelHoral, generalgmt and Darren Sweeney. I can do it. and I follow  Pavel Horal